# How to animate arcs in python (pygame zero)

Tags: python, animation, pygame

How would I simply animate these arcs by making them move upwards?

```
import random
import pygame
import math

WIDTH = 700
HEIGHT = 500

BLACK = (0, 0, 0)
WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
BLUE = (0, 0, 255)
GREEN = (0, 255, 0)
RED = (255, 0, 0)
BROWN = (101, 67, 33)
YELLOW = (255, 255, 0)

PI = math.pi

def draw():
    screen.fill(BLUE)
    chimney_smoke(400, 90, 50, 100)
```

I'm not sure what to put into the update function:

```
def update():

def chimney_smoke(x, y, w, h):
    pygame.draw.arc(screen.surface, BLACK, [x, y, w ,h], PI/2, PI, 2)
    pygame.draw.arc(screen.surface, BLACK, [x, y, w, h], 0, PI/2, 2)
    pygame.draw.arc(screen.surface, BLACK, [x, y, w, h], 3*PI/2, 2*PI, 2) 
    pygame.draw.arc(screen.surface, BLACK, [x, y, w, h], PI, 3*PI/2, 2)
```

I've made many attempts but can't seem to get it.  This is for class and I'm stuck.  Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: To make them move upward, instead of passing a hardcoded `90` for `y`, pass a different value for each frame that moves upward. (I assume your real program has a frame loop, or, if not, an event loop? If you don't have either, you can't animate anything, and you need to read a basic tutorial first.)

Comment: Thank you.  I'm using pygame zero so I believe it is just the update function as opposed to the event loop like it is in pygame.  Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I've never used pygame zero, but I assume that means it's doing either a frame loop or an event loop "under the covers" so you don't need to worry about it. Which is great. So you just modify the `y` value each time it calls your `update` or `draw` or whatever function.

Comment: From a quick look at [the tutorial](https://pygame-zero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/introduction.html#moving-the-alien), the recommended way to do this seems to be creating an `Actor` to keep track of each wisp of smoke, but you could just store a simple `smoke_y` variable instead.

Comment: Yes, I've been attempting to do it by attempting to store the y value in a variable that I'll call smoke_y.  The problem I'm running into is it's saying "smoke_y referenced before assignment".  I'm sure I'm just overlooking something simple.

Comment: You either forgot to set an initial value somewhere, or you need a `global smoke_y` at the top of the `update` function body so it modifies the global variable instead of trying to modify a non-existent local variable with the same name.

Comment: I have an update function that has "smoke_y -= 1" in it

Comment: Ok, thank you very much for your help.  I'll keep working on it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do is replace that hardcoded `90` with a variable, which you can update every time PyGame Zero calls your `update` function. Something like this:

```
smoke_y = 90

def update():
    global smoke_y
    smoke_y -= 1

def draw():
    screen.fill(BLUE)
    chimney_smoke(400, y, 50, 100)
```

Of course you may not want to move at exact the speed of 1 pixel per frame, and you probably want to add some logic for what happens when you hit the edge of the screen, but that should be enough to get you going.

Comment: That did it!!  I greatly appreciate the help!